# Is there a Java heap implementation that can remove arbitrary objects in O(logn) time?

Tags: java, time-complexity, heap, priority-queue

Suppose I have a set of objects in a PriorityQueue, so that I can conveniently determine and remove the min/max in log(n) time. But suppose I also want to be able to find and remove arbitrary objects from that PriorityQueue. Heaps will worst-case take `O(n)` time to find the object. And once removed, it takes `O(logn)` time to bubble up/down to restore the heap property.

But I can easily imagine an implementation of a heap that is supplemented with a HashMap that keeps track of the indices at which every object is. Then the lookup for an object to remove would be `O(1)` time, and the correction would be `O(logn)` so the removal of arbitrary objects would overall be `O(logn)`. Does such a data structure exist?

Comment: Not built in.  You would have to build it.

Comment: How important are duplicates? Mentioned queue. It can contain duplicates. If duplicates are possible, then map or set will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). It supports deletion by element in O(log n) time (`delete`) and also finding the first element (`first` and `pollFirst`). You should be able to effectively have a priority queue by using this interface.

Comment: Potential problem with `TreeSet` is that it doesn't allow duplicates. So every priority would have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way consists in manage a real tree, with pointers to the children and eventually to the parent. The problem with a array is that when you modify the heap, its entries move trough the array; this prevents to store array index or pointers in an additional data structure.

With a tree based implementation, you could perfectly store a pointer to the node and perform the remove in O(log n) (assuming that reprieving the node consumes at most O(log n)).

There is a C++ implementation that eventually could be translated to java. It is here:

https://github.com/lrleon/Aleph-w

The file containing the implementation is https://github.com/lrleon/Aleph-w/blob/master/tpl_dynBinHeap.H.

That is a correct implementation, but it is some complicated because of corner cases.

Comment: "this prevents to store array index or pointers in an additional data structure." Not true. It's very easy to write an array-based heap with an accompanying dictionary. Whenever you change an item's position in the array, you update its position in the dictionary. No corner cases, and no need for a tree.

Comment: I agree. However, I think that you have to update ~ O(log n) array indexes; those that move when you remove, which although leaves the remove O(log n), it requires additional logarithmic iterations. With a tree-based implementation, you perform only an O(log n) iteration. But yes, you are right. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can still (referring to @Strikeskids [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900236/7916438)) use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) if you extend your comparison with a unique part:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    private static int next=0;
    private final int ext=next++;
    private final int priority;
    public Item(int priority) {
        this.priority=priority;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return priority+" ("+ext+")";
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        if(priority!=o.priority)return priority-o.priority;
        return ext-o.ext;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item a=new Item(5);
        Item b=new Item(5);
        Item c=new Item(6);
        TreeSet<Item> set=new TreeSet<>();
        System.out.println(set.add(a));
        System.out.println(set.add(b));
        System.out.println(set.add(c));
        while(!set.isEmpty()){
            Item i=set.first();
            System.out.println(i);
            set.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

It works okay until the extension overflows (could be delayed with `long`), then it works okay-ish when there are both positive and negative extensions present (a possibility for further delay of this phase is to start from `Xy.MIN_VALUE` instead of `0`), and it will malfunction when extensions overflow and there are really-really long-starving items, and a new item comes with matching priority and extension. In theory it may be possible to find/keep track of the lowest extension still in use, and subtract it from all extensions (including itself) as part of some occasional housekeeping procedure - however it still could not help with the extremely long-starving case.